# How to solve 302 Issue in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form in django, which is working for rating. if a user will submit that form then it will save `procuct_id` and `user_id` in database, so that i can calculate the ratings which is given by users after login. But when i submit this form, it's showing `302 found`. so i checked after `HttpResponse` and it's printing `Hi`, please check my code and let me know where i am mistaking.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS=(
       ('New', 'New'),
       ('True', 'True'),
       ('False', 'False')
    )
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    rate=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ip=models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=['subject', 'comment', 'rate']
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def addcomment(request,id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') #get last url
    #return HttpResponse(url)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = Comment() #create relation with model
            #data.name = form.cleaned_data['name'] #get form input data
            data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            data.comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.product_id=id
            current_user=request.user
            data.user_id=current_user.id
            data.save() #save data to table
            messages.success(request, "Your Review has been Send. Thank you for your interest")
            return HttpResponse("Hello")

    return HttpResponse("Hi")
```

here is my `urls.py` file...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/addcomment/<int:id>', views.addcomment, name='addcomment'),

]
```

here is my `product.html` file....

```
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="top-review" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="review-top-tab">
                        {% if messages %}
                            {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}" role="alert">
                            {{ message }}
                        </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <form class="theme-form" method="POST" action="/product/addcomment/{{ product.id }}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="review">Review Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Enter your Review Subjects" required="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="review">Review Comment</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Wrire Your Comment Here"  rows="6"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    {% if user.id is not None %}
                                    <button class="btn btn-solid" type="submit">Submit Your Review</button>
                                         {% else %}
                                         You must be Loggedin to post a review.
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries, you don't need to fix anything. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `302 Found` redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header.
> It is therefore recommended to set the 302 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods.

As long as you aren't posting any sorts of data, I think you're fine.